# Revert changed line in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In visual studio 2022, we get the striped marker in the margin for modified lines

[image]

and when we click it we get a diff view

[image]

How do I revert the change of the line?

Answer (score 2):

To revert a single change, you click on it in the right pane of the Diff View:
This will bring up a popup where you can choose between staging the change for the single line change or reverting it.

[image]